# where().first vs find_by on mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Newbie to rails with mongoid.

Is there any performance impact difference between using

```
Model.where(:name => "XYZ").first
```

and

```
Model.find_by(:name => "XYZ")
```

I see in console that both these queries use "Limit 1" in query (when I used on Postgres). Is it the same behavior in Mongoid?

Answer (score 3):

It seems `find_by` uses `where` and `first` internally

```
def find_by(attrs = {})
  result = where(attrs).find_first
  if result.nil? && Mongoid.raise_not_found_error
    raise(Errors::DocumentNotFound.new(self, attrs))
  end
  yield(result) if result && block_given?
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments above have explained the internals. I saw a comparison on performance. This is the github code and the result link.
[Performance Comparison](https://gist.github.com/bartoszkopinski/8049510)

[image]